# I can't access my Gmail account

Tags: gmail, google-account

My account this gaussian,_1992 cannot be accessed. When I try to log in with the password I used it does not open for some months now.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either follow the directions for password recovery, or contact google support directly.

From the google support site:

Reset your password

1. Go to the Account support page.
   https://accounts.google.com/signin/recovery
2. Follow the instructions. You'll be asked some questions to confirm it's your account. Answer as best you can.
3. Reset your password. Choose a strong password that you haven't already used with this account. Learn how to create a strong password.

If that does not work they provide this link for troubleshooting and assisting with recovering your account https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/2402620